# SQL Server Management Studio: returning multiple max values from a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, ssms

I am currently learning SQL and have done a sub query on a database and now want to take the highest version number. But have found out you can't use max on the subquery

```
Day|Version
---+-------
1  |1
1  |1
1  |2
1  |2
```

Along with a bunch of other data in the row. I want to select the rows with the highest version number.

Any suggestions? First time poster so sorry for the poor formatting

Cheers

Andrew

Comment: Where is the query you used?

Comment: Please sdit your question to include sample data, a streamlined version of the query and expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select row with max value when duplicate rows exist in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879550/how-to-select-row-with-max-value-when-duplicate-rows-exist-in-sql-server)