# SQL Select highest value where duplicate ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with the columns:

```
ID,        DayNumber, Mfm, value
432080971, 1,         15,  57
432080971, 1,         15,  59
432080978, 3,         15,  54
432080978, 4,         45,  54
```

Unfortunately there are some duplicated entries. What I'd like is a select statement that returns the table without duplicated ID, Daynumber and Mfm, and where if there is a double entry to select the row with the higher value.

So, as an example the above entries would be returned as:

```
ID,        DayNumber, Mfm, value
432080971, 1,         15,  59
432080978, 3,         15,  54
432080978, 4,         45,  54
```

I'm using sql server management studio running sql server 2012

Comment: use `group by`.

Comment: `select id,max(value) from table group by id` something like this

Comment: Asked and answered hundreds of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select row with max value when duplicate rows exist in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879550/how-to-select-row-with-max-value-when-duplicate-rows-exist-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top (1) 
with ties ID, DayNumber, Mfm, value
from
table
order by row_number() over (partiton by
                            ID, DayNumber, Mfm
                            order by value desc)
```

Comment: A rather unknowledgeable person must have downvoted this answer.  For this case, I think `GROUP BY` is best, but this is definitely reasonable (particularly if the user wants t he `Mfm` associated with the maximum value).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Group By` clause and use the aggregate function `MAX` to get the highest value of the group. Something like this:

```
Select ID, DayNumber, Mfm, Max(value) From 
From your_table
Group By ID, DayNumber, Mfm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    ID, DayNumber, Mfm, max(value)
    from table
group by ID, DayNumber, Mfm
```