# If 2+ Records, Keep Highest Premium

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen queries that use max(value) with group by to select highest value where duplicate ID ([SQL Select highest value where duplicate ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523579/sql-select-highest-value-where-duplicate-id)), however, I believe I'm not applying the approach correctly and was hoping someone could assist.

I need to do a select into statement, as I'll be referencing this table at a later point. Keeping that in mind, my code looks like this:

```
select class, record_id, max(salesprice) as salesprice, category, zone
into ##weeklysalestable
from ##salestable
where class in ('residential')
group by class, record id, category, zone
order by  record_id, class, category,zone
```

The problem is that SQL is prompting me to name column 3 (so i added that to the code above) which then I believe is causing the output to not drop the duplicate with the lower salesprice. Goal is simply to keep the the record_id with the highest sales price.

Can max() not be applied in this scenario? If so, is there an alternative approach?

Sample source data:

| class | record_id | salesprice | category | zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AR2695 | 13 | NEW | NE |
| A1 | AR2695 | 26 | NEW | NE |
| B2 | AL5397 | 18 | USL | SE |
| C3 | AM3920 | 39 | NEW | SW |

Desired Output:

| record_id | class | salesprice | category | zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AR2695 | A1 | 26 | NEW | NE |
| AL5397 | B2 | 18 | USL | SE |
| AM3920 | C3 | 39 | NEW | SW |

Any advice would be great.

Comment: The combination GROUP BY and SELECT DISTINCT raises many eyebrows... (Hint: Your GROUP BY returns no duplicates, no need to do SELECT DISTINCT.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Naming the output column didn't have anything to do with your issue. It allowed the query to execute whereby you observed the data. Perhaps that's just a poorly phrased sentence but if not then be sure to contemplate the post hoc fallacy involved.

Comment: `max()` operates by reducing a list of values in a column to a single output (aggregate). It doesn't not select rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using the window function `row_number() over()` in a subquery

```
select class,
       record_id,
       salesprice,
       category, 
       zone
into ##weeklysalestable
from ( Select *
             ,rn = row_number() over (partition by class,category,zone order by salesprice desc)    -- assuming `record_id` doesn't need to be in the `partition`
        From ##salestable
        where class in ('residential')
     ) A
Where RN = 1
```

Another option is using `WITH TIES`  (a nudge less performant)

```
select top 1 with ties 
       class,
       record_id,
       salesprice,
       category, 
       zone
into ##weeklysalestable
from ##salestable
where class in ('residential')
order by row_number() over (partition by class,category,zone order by salesprice desc)  -- assuming `record_id` doesn't need to be in the `partition`
```